# Grub not showing installed kernels

Tags: 12.04, grub2

Although I have several kernel versions in /boot and having them in my grub.cfg, they are not displayed in the grub boot menu.

Running *update-grub* seems to work, as it puts the kernels in the *grub.cfg* in */boot/grub*. Issueing it gives the following output:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
cat: /boot/grub/video.lst: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: Fehler: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: Fehler: no such disk.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: Fehler: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: Fehler: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: Fehler: no such disk.
done
```

I don't know how to fix that problem. Reinstalling grub via live cd did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or Live-USB.

- choose "Try Ubuntu"
- connect to Internet
- open a new Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then type:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Press Enter.
- Then type:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```
- Press Enter

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, in the end it recognizes that I am working with a encrypted partition: Encrypted partition detected. Please retry after opening it (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory) But I am not sure what exactly from that big page I need to do, to enable it.

Comment: It seems you have an have encrypted your partition so you have to decypt before you can login read the page link given for you

Comment: Yes, it was a encrypted partition and opening it helped.